# Sql Server 2008 Spatial query slow

Tags: sql-server-2008, geospatial

I have a database with a datatable within 2 000 000 lines with 1 geography type field containting Point.
In another datatable I have 600 lines with 1 geography type field containting Polygon.

```
This query to retrieve all the POINT in a POLYGON is very slow

SELECT ID_POINT, ID_POLYGON FROM 
             (SELECT ID_POINT, COORD FROM POINT_TABLE) as POINT
             (SELECT ID_POLYGON, COORD FROM POLYGON_TABLE WHERE ID_POLYGON = 276) as POLYGON
         WHERE
             (POINT.Coord.STIntersects(POLYGON.COORD) = 1)
```

I have 1 spatial index in each table like this :

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [IDX_POLYGON_COORD] ON [dbo].[POLYGON] 
(
    [COORD]
)USING  GEOGRAPHY_GRID 
WITH (
GRIDS =(LEVEL_1 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_2 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_3 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_4 = MEDIUM), 
CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 16, PAD_INDEX  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Could you help me to speed up this query ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

This will mostly depend in how spread out your data is, as to whether the index you have on the Point table (I assume such an index exists) is appropriately sized with its Medium grid sizes.

Ideally, your execution plan should show a seek on Polygon to fetch row 276, and then a Spatial Index Seek on Point to fetch the ones that intersect with the polygon. It shouldn't be slow. But if your Polygon table isn't also indexed on id_polygon, then you might find it's trying to join on the geographies before filtering to that row.